# Is it possible to mirror a model using only rotation?

Tags: mirror

I need to mirror a 3d model using a game engine that only has rotation (no flip function). Is it possible to mirror a model using only rotation (X Z Y)?

Comment: I don't know about rotation, but scaling an object along any given axis by -1 causes a mirror flip along that axis. Example: `Scale(S), X, -1` will mirror flip on the X axis.

Comment: yes that works thank you

Comment: you can only mirror with rotation objects that have an axis of symmetry, but yes, what chris said is the way to go